# Meaning of I(Var^(-1)) in r

Tags: r, multiple-regression

I have a test dataset on which I run the following regression analysis in r:

`fit <- lm(Cost ~ Slope + YardDist + Removals + TreeVol, data = test)`

I get an r-squared of 0.83

Next I change the regression equation to:

`fit <- lm(Cost ~ Slope + YardDist + Removals+ I(TreeVol^(-0.82)), data = test)`

I get an r-squared of 0.9872.

I am wondering what the expression of `I(TreeVol^(-0.82))` exactly means?

When I hold all variables constant besides TreeVol, the TreeVol/Cost graph looks like the red one. I guess that is related but I don't fully understand it.
[image]

Comment: How did you come up with the power of $-0.82$?

Comment: I tested around until I got the best results for r-squared.

Comment: @whuber is there a better way to come up with that number?

Comment: I'm just mystified by how you could be "testing around" with an `R` expression without knowing what that expression means. I suspect you might be better served by explaining what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: FWIW, the `I(foo)` form in `R` models basically means to compute the `foo` expression without interpreting it as special 'model language'. So for your case, it is equivalent to making a dummy variable `newvar <- TreeVol^-0.82`, appending it to `test` and adding a `newvar` term to your model.

Comment: I have 10000 testdatasets with a value for the dependent variable cost. The independent variables are Slope, YardDist, TreeVol, Removals. I am trying to come up with an equation for cost. I did another testrun where I held all variables besides TreeVol constant and the graph above showed up. So I figured it needs to be something like x^(−n).

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_curve) and focus on adjR2 not R2 if you are really looking for fit